# Gitlab runner and Repository in different VM’s

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have repositories in one VM and Gitlab runner was registered on another VM and gitlab exists on another VM.How can I communicate between these VM’s to implement gitlab CI/CD pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your GitLab Runner, it asks for a token as well as the URL of your GitLab instance -- as long as both VMs are on the same network, you should be able to set up your Runner just fine.

The "GitLab URL" could either be an actual URL (if you have DNS set up for the GitLab instance) or just by IP address (ie http://111.222.111.222).